# Cant connect to any github repository from my netbeans 20

Tags: github, netbeans, repository, git-repo

I'm encountering an issue where I can access public projects without any problem, but when I attempt to access a private project, I receive an error message stating 'Cannot connect to the remote repository.'

I've verified that my access token is correct and tried using it, but the issue persists. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer was the access token all along, i made another access token(classic) but which is for repo---full control of private repositories---, i know it's stupid, it took me 2 hours to know this.